# Android NavigationDrawer with PreferenceActivity

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, preferenceactivity

Can any one suggest me how to implement the Navigation drawer in the preference Activities ?

**My JavaCode.**

```
package com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
public class AppPreferences extends PreferenceActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.as);
    }
}
```

**My XML code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <EditTextPreference android:title="Your Name"
                      android:key="username"
                      android:summary="Please provide your username"></EditTextPreference>
  <CheckBoxPreference android:title="Application Updates"
                      android:defaultValue="false"
                      android:summary="This option if selected will allow the application to check for latest versions."
                      android:key="applicationUpdates" />
  <ListPreference     android:title="Download Details"
                      android:summary="Select the kind of data that you would like to download"
                      android:key="downloadType"

                     />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Please someone advice me. I am awaiting for your responses.

Answer (score 3):

Try using PreferenceFragment with FragmentActivity instead of PreferenceActivity.

Comment: Do you know any sample which supports Navigation Drawer with PreferenceFragment ?

Comment: Here is how you create a Drawer: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html
The class of the Fragment you insert into the page is a totally indeoendent stuff.

Comment: I am using that sample only at the moment with the support of Activity. Now I am trying to change to add the navigation drawer to   already working preference Screen. Can i do it with this ?

Comment: You have to use ActionbarActivity if you want to support devices running lower than API level 11. Otherwise a regular Activity should do it.

Comment: My app support starts with ICS only.

Comment: Than I think you can use PreferenceActivity along with the provided tutorial

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to use together PreferenceActivity and NavigationDrawer due to two mutually exclusive options:

1. `PreferenceActivity` has to inflate its own internal layout.
2. `DrawerLayout` must be **root** element of layout.

So, I think this is the end of the road.